# How to Differentiate this Matrix product

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve the matrix equations for linear regression and it leads me to the following differentiation.  I cannot find an explanation on how to do it on the Internet, only the result being quoted.  Can someone explain to me how to differentiate this?

$\frac{d}{dw} w^{T}X^{T}Xw$

```
w = d x 1 vector

X = N x d matrix
```

Comment: The process to derive has already been given in the answer.
I'll just add that once you've derived it, it's pretty easy to memorize. Thinking as a polynomial, $w^T A w$ is a quadratic in $w$, so its derivative with respect to $w$ is $2Aw$ when $A$ is symmetric. Similarly, if $b$ is a vector, the derivative of $b^T w$ is $b$. Note the transpose though. (If $A$ is not symmetric, $w^T A w$ would become $(A + A^T)w$. This kind of explains the factor $2$ in a sense.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we want to differentiate the function $f \colon\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$, given by $f(w) = w^tX^tXw$. Let's follow the definition, we have for $h, w\in \mathbb R^d$:
\begin{align*}
  f(w+h) &= (w+h)^tX^tX(w+h)\\
         &= w^tX^tXw + h^tX^tXw + w^tX^tXh + h^tX^tXh\\
         &= f(w) + 2w^tX^tXh + h^tX^tXh
\end{align*}
Now $h\mapsto 2w^tX^tXh$ is linear in $h$ and 
$$ \|h^tX^tXh\| \le \|X\|\|X^t\|\|h\|^2 = o(\|h\|) $$
so $f'(w)h = 2w^tX^tXh$ for each $w$, $h$.